# How can we hide apps in android programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0, device-policy-manager

I am trying to hide an app in android studio.

I have created an DeviceAdminReceiver that listens when app is given admin rights.

```
#MyDevicePolicyReceiver.java
public class MyDevicePolicyReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Truiton's Device Admin Disabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Truiton's Device Admin is now enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
        CharSequence disableRequestedSeq = "Requesting to disable Device Admin";
        return disableRequestedSeq;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Log.i("qwerty", "MyDevicePolicyReciever Received: " + intent.getAction());
    }
    public static void enableApp(Context ctx, String pk){
        try {
            DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            ComponentName localComponent = getComponentName(ctx);
            dpm.setApplicationHidden(localComponent, pk, false);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("qwerty",e.toString());
            Log.d("qwerty",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I am using setApplicationHidden of DevicePolicyManager to hide the app from the app menu (in disableapp method).

I am receiving following error on `dpm.setApplicationHidden(localComponent, pk, false);`:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Admin ComponentInfo{com.example.applocker/com.example.applocker.broadcast.MyDevicePolicyReceiver} does not own the profile.
```

Comment: at first set device owner command (cosu mode)

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dpm set-device-owner com.example.applocker/.MyDevicePolicyReceiver");` this is the command i am running.

Comment: The device owner or profile owner app needs to be set during the setup of the device or work profile. Unlike for device admin, it cannot be changed after setup without factory reset (or removing the work profile). To configure your app to be a device owner or profile owner, see the Android EMM Developers documentation.

It's quite complicated to implement this in your own app, and instead you should consider using the Android Management API which offers the same features as a simpler cloud API. For example the equivalent of setPermissionGrantState is PermissionGrant.

Comment: make sure you remove all accounts (Google) from phone

Comment: @RaviPatel can you share a code walk through.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya how can i do that in user's system.

Comment: here is a sample code for permission :- https://codeshare.io/aV7kA3

Comment: Can you explain a little on what provisionManagedProfile does